How to get spring custom authentication provider to work
I'm using spring-security 6 to implement custom authentication. Actual authentication is based on signature which is sent in a header. Therefore I have tried to implement a sample to get the structure working. Below are my code.
AuthenticatoinProvider:
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    final String name = authentication.getName();
    final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    if (!"admin".equals(name) || !"system".equals(password)) {
        return null;
    }
    return authenticateAgainstThirdPartyAndGetAuthentication(name, password);
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return true;
}

private static UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticateAgainstThirdPartyAndGetAuthentication(String name, String password) {
    final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
    final UserDetails principal = new User(name, password, grantedAuths);
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, grantedAuths);
  }
}

Fitler:
@Component
public class EverybodyAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        // THIS IS ONLY FOR TESTS. TO GET THIS WORK SENDING HARD CODED TOKEN. THIS SHOULD BE
        // CREATED FROM HEADER VALUES.
        customAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin",
                "system"));
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

Security Config:
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo")
public class SecurityConfig{

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                           AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                           EverybodyAuthenticationFilter every) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests(expressionInterceptUrlRegistry ->
                        expressionInterceptUrlRegistry.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .addFilterBefore(every, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .build();
    }
}

Controller:
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private static final String HOME_VIEW = "home/index";

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request){
        return HOME_VIEW;
    }
}

In this code EverybodyAuthenticationFilter send hardcoded token just for testing. Therefore my understanding is this should work for all the requests. However I get 403 error. I came across following discussion where it says with spring-security 6 custome authentication provider works differently.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12602
How can i get this to work ?

Why are you using Filter when you are providing Authentication Provider ? Also you don't need authManager, spring will automatically find your custom  Authentication Provider and inject into SecurityFilterChain.

spring security 6 does not invoke custom authentication provider.

It does. I have used it. Again why using Filter ? Also I would suggest to implement UserDetailsService for custom authentication

I'm trying to authenticate user using a custom header value. This header has signature and custom auth provider is there to validate this signature and decide if it authenticated or not. This is actually existing project and i'm trying to migrate to spring boot 3. I found this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12602 saying with spring boot 3 custom auth provider not invoked. This is also my experience. I'm trying to solve this issue in separate project.

You will have to set authentication in the filter itself SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication) before filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
If possible, could you can share minimal reproducible code, so that we can look into it further

Yes, its in https://github.com/mayuraviraj/springboot-custom-authentication-provider-master . I tried to set the authentication also ( in this case hardcoded authenticated token) but still not working.

several problems here, you should inject the AuthenticationManager and not your custom AuthenticationProvider, ideally make a custom Authentication to which yur AuthenticationProvider will react instead of this. Your filter is marked @Component and will be registered by Spring Boot in the regular filter chain already. Remove the @Component create an @Bean method to create the filter and another to create a FilterRegistrationBean to disable the automatic registration of this bean.

In addition I would suggest to extend the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and implement the attemptAuthentication method. This filter will properly set the authenticated user into the Spring Security needed objects, fire events etc.

Lets do a bit more integration with Spring Security and instead of the OncePerRequestFilter extend the AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and let the filter use the AuthenticationManager.
public class EverybodyAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  public EverybodyAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super("/**", authenticationManager);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin", "system"));
  }
}

And yes there are no annotations on this class.
Next to register this in the filter chain with Spring security create a custom DSL and apply that to the regular configuration.
public class CustomSecurityConfigurer extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<CustomSecurityConfigurer, HttpSecurity> {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
    http.addFilterBefore(new EverybodyAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  public static CustomSecurityConfigurer customSecurityConfigurer() {
    return new CustomSecurityConfigurer();
  }
}

This will do 2 things it will re-use the shared pre-configured AuthenticationManager which will include your custom AuthenticationProvider and register it only in the security filter chain. The latter due this not being a spring managed bean anymore.
Lastly apply this DSL to the regular configuration.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.apply(CustomSecurityConfigurer.customSecurityConfigurer());
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests( auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
        .build();
  }
}

Or when using Spring Boot 3.2 or up
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.with(CustomSecurityConfigurer.customSecurityConfigurer(), Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.authorizeHttpRequests( auth -> auth.anyRequest().authenticated()).build();
  }
}

With this you integrate better with Spring Security and your CustomAuthenticationProvider will be consulted. When issuing a request you can see that your filter and provider is being used in the logs.
2024-04-24T11:27:46.430+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@d34f785, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@35ff8be7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3984cdbb, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@35c10b4c, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@544d6d67, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@53bd8b05, com.example.demo.config.EverybodyAuthenticationFilter@732016bc, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7667877e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6dad8960, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1eeb4095, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2654da2e, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@3601de4a]] (1/1)
2024-04-24T11:27:46.430+02:00 DEBUG 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /home
2024-04-24T11:27:46.430+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2024-04-24T11:27:46.430+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2024-04-24T11:27:46.431+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2024-04-24T11:27:46.432+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2024-04-24T11:27:46.433+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/12)
2024-04-24T11:27:46.433+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2024-04-24T11:27:46.433+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2024-04-24T11:27:46.433+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2024-04-24T11:27:46.433+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking EverybodyAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2024-04-24T11:27:46.433+02:00 TRACE 59161 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with CustomAuthenticationProvider (1/1)

